# Get superscript numbers followed one by other as one string

Tags: regex, swift

I use following code to get a superscript numbers:

```
var pattern: NSRegularExpression?
do {
  try pattern = NSRegularExpression(pattern: "[¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹⁰]", options: NSRegularExpressionOptions.CaseInsensitive)
} catch {
  print("Error getting pattern")
}
```

How can I get a string from superscript numbers with two or more digits in, like ¹² etc.

Comment: Add a `+` quantifier after the character class: `[¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹⁰]+`

Comment: @stribizhev thank you. It works. Post it like answer, please)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add a `+` quantifier:

```
[¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹⁰]+
            ^
```

The `+` means *match 1 or more occurrences of the preceding subpattern*.

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oH8sJ9/1)

See more details on [regex quantifiers in the *Mastering Quantifiers* section at rexegg.com](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html).

> A regex quantifier such as `+` tells the regex engine to match a certain quantity of the character, token or subexpression immediately to its left.